# BitchX - Segmentation fault

Tags: macos, installation, irc

```
Last login: Tue Mar 16 15:29:57 on ttys002
mbp:~ alexus$ sudo port install bitchx
Password:
--->  Computing dependencies for bitchx
--->  Fetching ncursesw
--->  Attempting to fetch ncurses-5.7.tar.gz from http://distfiles.macports.org/ncurses
--->  Verifying checksum(s) for ncursesw
--->  Extracting ncursesw
--->  Configuring ncursesw
--->  Building ncursesw
--->  Staging ncursesw into destroot
--->  Installing ncursesw @5.7_0+darwin_10
--->  Activating ncursesw @5.7_0+darwin_10
--->  Cleaning ncursesw
--->  Fetching ncurses
--->  Verifying checksum(s) for ncurses
--->  Extracting ncurses
--->  Configuring ncurses
--->  Building ncurses
--->  Staging ncurses into destroot
--->  Installing ncurses @5.7_0+darwin_10
--->  Activating ncurses @5.7_0+darwin_10
--->  Cleaning ncurses
--->  Fetching bitchx
--->  Attempting to fetch ircii-pana-1.1-final.tar.gz from http://voxel.dl.sourceforge.net/bitchx
--->  Verifying checksum(s) for bitchx
--->  Extracting bitchx
--->  Applying patches to bitchx
--->  Configuring bitchx
--->  Building bitchx
--->  Staging bitchx into destroot
--->  Installing bitchx @1.1_1+darwin
--->  Activating bitchx @1.1_1+darwin
--->  Cleaning bitchx
mbp:~ alexus$ BitchX
BitchX - Based on EPIC Software Labs epic ircII (1998).
Version (BitchX-1.1-final) -- Date (20040326).
Process [30864]
Segmentation fault
mbp:~ alexus$
```

any ideas why is it doing "Segmentation fault" and how to troubleshoot it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The MacPorts team is [aware](http://trac.macports.org/ticket/21897) that it segfaults, but say that unless the BitchX team fix it, there's probably no hope that the MacPorts team will take the time to fix it.

BitchX's current version (1.1) was released in 2004, and has [unresolved security issues](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BitchX#Security) known since 2007. So the odds that it'll get fixed seem pretty slim.

To pursue this further you might consider using another IRC client to join #BitchX on EFnet and see if that channel even exists anymore and if anyone responds, but given the apparent hacker/punk nature of the BitchX development team, I doubt any good will come of that.

Answer (score -2):

God knows. Wrong library somewhere, most likely.

The next step is to build that bad boy (girl?) from source. If nothing else, it'll give you a better error message.